# jQuery Function Recursion - I'm lost on this one

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I am new to jQuery and I don't understand why I'm seeing this "end of if" line in the console log. If toggleBox calls itself just before the "end of if" console log line, how is the console.log() function ever processed?

It seems like lines 1 and 2 would just repeat but, somehow, line 3 is running. It looks like it is just jumping around. Would the toggleBox call actually jump back to itself just before box.fadeToggle is called, finish the if block, and then jump back up to the box.fadeToggle for some reason?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var box     = $("#box");
var para = $("p");
var i   = 0;

para.text(i);

function toggleBox(i) {
    console.log($.now() + " 1. entering toggleBox. i=" + i);
    box.fadeToggle(2000, function() {
        console.log($.now() + " 2. after fade time. i=" + i);
        i++;
        if (i < 4) {
            para.text(i);
            toggleBox(i);
            console.log($.now() + " 3. end of if. i=" + i);
        };
    });
};

toggleBox(i);
```

});

The console output:

69387 1. entering toggleBox. i=0

71398 2. after fade time. i=0

71399 1. entering toggleBox. i=1

71400 3. end of if. i=1

73396 2. after fade time. i=1

73397 1. entering toggleBox. i=2

73397 3. end of if. i=2

75398 2. after fade time. i=2

75399 1. entering toggleBox. i=3

75399 3. end of if. i=3

77399 2. after fade time. i=3

Comment: The async part starts with your callback to `fadeToggle()`. That's where the flow will change, and why you go back to `1.` before you see `3.`. Put the `3.` before `toggleBox(i)`, and it'll be more like what you're expecting.

Comment: Ah ha. So there are two "threads" running then? I now see that fadeToggle sends a time limit and that function counts down (somewhere) and then runs the callback function afterward, while my own code is running in the meantime somehow. Is that the async you are talking about?

Comment: Pretty much. It's actually a single thread, but with a scheduler for later execution. The way JavaScript animations work is that they incrementally adjust the CSS property using asynchronous function calls *(via `setTimeout` or `setInterval`)*. If they didn't do this asynchronously, the single thread would be blocked until the animation finished, and so the entire window environment would be locked up. And then yes, after the full animation is complete, your callback function will be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

```
box.fadeToggle(2000; function
```

starts the fadeToggle and register the callback then returns. This means that `toggleBox(i);` immediately returns without going deeper, so the following `console.log` is executed.

You have to realize this isn't really a recursion as the callback will be called only later, after the animation, thus letting the current instruction flow go on. You'd have the same phenomenon with any asynchronous operation.

Comment: So it can do two things at once? The API desc says "If supplied, the callback is fired once the animation is complete."

So fadeToggle is running (and counting up or down, I guess) while the code in this file, app.js, continues on? Is that the asyncronous operation you reference?

Should I understand that as jQuery functions can run while my own code is stepping through?

Comment: Yes, animations are handled using setInterval and setTimeout : most of the time the JS thread does nothing. So any function launching an animation will immediately end. That's also why a callback is necessary, because you have no other way to know when the animation ends since the launching function immediately finishes.